# Organize SQL in components with interfaces and private code

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, interface, sql-server-2008-r2, components

I am reworking an application with much logic implemented in SQL (MS SQL Server 2008 R2). Logically the business logic can be split in many distinct components.

Current implementation is very unstructured: each procedure, function, view accesses and writes data everywhere. I would like to organzie the application in smaller units as I would do it with an JavaEE application: small JARs with public interfaces, but the persistence layer and business logic implementation is hidden.

Is there any default concept how to define "public interface tables or stored procedures" beside to "prive interface tables or stored procedures". In the first step it might be enough to use naming conventions. But if there is a better way, please let me know.

[Edit] As we are restricted to use MS SQL Server only: What do you think about the concept of defining separate schemes within the same DB for each module?

Answer (score 0):

There's no real equivalent to this other than access control of the database tables and procedures, which is different from how a OO system organizes visibility.

The best case scenario would be to move as much logic from the sprocs into the application layer and deal with the messiness there.  If this isn't likely to happen, I would consider refactoring your functions so that they perform only single operations (logically).  If necessary, you could group similar sprocs under a single one and have the application layer operate only through those functions.

Comment: I agree that persistence layer should not contain any logic. In our special case DB is not responsible for persistence only but will contain logic in future as well. That's nothing I can change.